# Pass two variables sequentially

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell

In `Unix shell`,`git clone <url>` will prompt user for username then password.

I defined `$username` and `$password` variables.

how could I pass two variables to the command in order.

I have tried
`echo $password | echo $username | git clone <url>`
,which did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass variable like so:

```
username="xyz"
password="123"
echo  "git clone https://$username:$password@github.com/$username/repository.git"
```

Output:

```
git clone https://xyz:123@github.com/xyz/repository.git
```

Comment: Ya, I know this is feasible. I am using Jenkins to automate the process that includes a series of Git commands. But if I do the one like this, when the password and username are wrong, the GitHub API will send the response containing the username and password and Jenkins will log it, disclosing the username and password to the public haha.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about how to pass username/password in `git clone` command in bash. You should clarify this in your question for clarity. If you are concerned about security, consider configuring your username/password in git (`git config`) so that dont have to enter it every time.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can do this.  What you probably *should* do, because it's more secure, is use a configuration where the script doesn't have to contain and pass the username and password.  For example, you could set up ssh, or you could use a credential helper.  (Details depend on your environment, so I'd recommend searching for existing questions and answers re: how to set those up.)

If you still want to have the script pass the values, you basically have two choices:  You can use a form of the git command that takes the values on the command line (see brokenfoot's answer), or you can pass the values on STDIN (which is the approach you're attempting, but doesn't work quite the way you're attempting it).

When you use `|`, you're sending the "standard output" of the command on the left to the "standard input" of the command on the right.  So when you chain commands like you show, the first `echo` is sending output to the second `echo` - which ignores it.  That's not what you want.

You would need a single command that outputs the username, and end-of-line character, the password, and another end-of-line character.  That's not easy to do with echo (at least, not portably).  You could do something like

```
git clone *url* <<EOF
$username
$password
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me pretend the question is neither git-related no security-related
and my answer to the literal question "How to pass two variables to a
program" is:

```
( echo $username; echo $password ) | git clone 'url'
```

That is, just output two strings separated by a newline (`echo` adds the newline); or do it in one
call to `echo`:

```
echo "$username
$password" | git clone 'url'
```